# Directive not parsing initial value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-directive

Currently I'm working on a directive that has to show a number as a currency whenever the user is not focused on the input field. This works great up until the point I'm reloading the data from my server and giving the input field a starting value.

Whenever I initialize the value of the input field the parsing doesn't apply until the user has focused and exited the input field (Which is normal behavior). I am trying apply the format of the number even if the user hasn't entered (focus) and exited (blur) the field yet.

[image: Representation of the problem]

The left field is the input when I load the page and the right field is the input after I focused on it and exited the field. I need the right representation to be shown even if the user hasn't interacted with the input yet.

I have tried to apply the pipe in the constructor and on ngInit but the value at those points is still '0' so I don't think I can do it that way. I have also tried to bind on the ngOnChanges lifecycle and the 'change' hostListener event but neither works.

Is there any way to make this work or will this become a feature on my page?

My directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCurrencyFormatter]'
})
export class CurrencyFormatterDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    private el: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor(
      private elementRef: ElementRef,
      private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      // This doesn't work. value at this point is an empty string.
      this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.el.value);
    }

    @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value'])
    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log('change'); // only triggers when user changes the value.
                               // Not when value is set during initialization.
    }

    @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
    onFocus(value) {
      this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.parse(value);
    }

    @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
    onBlur(value) {
      this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
    }

}
```

My html input:

```
<input type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="testNumber"
       appCurrencyFormatter />
```

`testNumber` is just initialized on the value 22221 in `ngOnInit(){...}`

I'm using the latest version of angular6 at the moment.

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to use a Pipe instead of a Directive

Comment: This has probably something to do with change detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ngOnInit` use the `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook. This ensures that the value is already initialized.

```
export class CurrencyFormatterDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 // ...

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.el.value);
  }
```

Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxwdkh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

For further information on `AfterViewChecked`, have a look at the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview).

Comment: I added this but it didn't work. It still had the same result. A console log still shows the value of el as an empty string.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong lifecycle hook. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

That's because the directive needs time to grab the model. you can try doing something like this:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDir]'
})
export class MyDirDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value)
    }, 0);
  }

}
```

Comment: This works! But it kinda feels like a hack (although I get why this solves it). If no better answer is given I'll mark this as the answer.